# Researching potential smart contract use in streamlining spare parts supply chain

Tags: smart-contract, blockchain

I'm researching the potential for blockchain smart contracts to be utilized for streamlining order fulfillment against requirements contracts; and possibly other contracting/acquisition uses.

By way of example, when a Government agency wants to contract for spare parts/part replenishment as such items are required, the Government may negotiate an indefinite-delivery requirements contract containing all the main contract terms and conditions.  Then, when the need for a specific part arises, a supply planner will input a requisition for the item (i.e., a purchase request), which would flow to finance person (puts the money on the requirement).  Then, the full requisition would go to a purchaser, who prepares an Order for the item.  The order is routed to the vendor, who then fulfills and ships the item.  After receipt, inspection, and/or acceptance of the item, the vendor's invoice is processed for payment.  Lots of different hands and documents in the process and time consuming, but perceived as necessary for assuring accountability and auditability.

Is there any granular data/information that could walk me through how a blockchain smart contract could be utilized to pair-down/eliminate the inefficiencies, speed up the process, and assure security, transparency and accountability?

Answer (score 1):

I think that an NFT would be sufficient for this, off the top of my head.

You could create a smart contract that generates a 1/1 NFT for every spare part when sufficient ADA is sent to the smart contracts UTXO, with the relevant metadata attached for the purchase order. i.e buyer organization ID, shipping destination, shipping details, any other relevant information.

If you wanted to really get into the guts of something like that, you may have a QR code attached to the part you ordered, and would be able to scan and update the location at particular waypoints, and consume an "LocationUpdate" endpoint in the smart contract to update the NFTs metadata to show the most recent location, but that would require a hardware solution as well. In the short term you may have a warehouse receiver through some kind of simple to use UI, confirm receipt/QC inspection and complete the smart contract.

I don't see why the Supply Planner + Finance + purchaser can't be one person in this scenario.